# How to make an iOS app Landscape ONLY

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, orientation, device-orientation

Seems like a simple thing to do right? Go to the Target's Summary tab and set "Supported Interface Orientations" to Landscape Right only. You would think that would mean the app would be landscape only. But no.

On a device running 5.1 for example, if you open the app and hold the phone in the correct landscape right position you will see the view rotated 90 degrees counterclockwise, as if it think it's supposed to be in portrait mode, unless you add something like this:

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    // Return YES for supported orientations
    return UIInterfaceOrientationIsLandscape(interfaceOrientation);
}
```

But that only works for one view controller, and who knows if it works on all OS versions.

So how do you make an app landscape only? Do I have to add that code to every single view controller in the app? I do not need any rotation. All my views are designed in Landscape. I just want the app to open in Landscape Right mode and stay that way. And I want to support iOS 5 and up.

Comment: in adition to the answers below, you can also change the orientation by deselecting the orientation buttons at the project level on the first page where the picture of the device with different orientations are. just pross on the ones you don't want and all of the views will be turning to that orientation. no code just buttons. easy :)

Comment: I have done that, like I described in my post. It doesn't work on ios5.

Answer (score 3):

There are new methods introduced that you have to implement along with the old one they are as below

```
-(BOOL)shouldAutorotate
{
    return YES;
}

-(NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscape;
}
```

Comment: I have to put this in every view controller in my app?

Comment: YES.. with your old function

Comment: You only need to put it in your root view controller.

Answer (score 0):

In Xcode you can navigate to your project settings -> summary -> iPhone/iPod deployment info. Here you can select the supported interface orientations. You can also edit the 'Supported interface orientations' array in your application's info.plist by adding the desired interface orientations application wide.

Comment: I mentioned that in my original question. That does not work on 5.1.

Answer (score 0):

In the info.plist put the orientation to landscape